# Google Share button not showing properly if originaly hidden

Tags: jquery, css, google-plus

Does anyone know of a solution to how the Google Share button doesn't show properly if it is originally hidden using css `display:none` on its parent `div` and then being shown using jquery `.show()`?

Due to the problem im facing I don't see what code would be relevant to add but I have made a very basic [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oxe968ux/) that shows the issue.

Comment: Is that the actual HTML etc?

Comment: That isn't the html I'm using in the site I'm making but it replicates the circumstance that's causing the problem. (Its an image gallery using `fadeIn` `fadeOut` with the last `fadeIn` having the share options for the entire gallery).

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the way the button is constructed (mostly tables from what I can see). Could you use `visibility` instead?

Comment: Seems like it almost tries to detect the space its in (96px vs 80px). You could get around it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/oxe968ux/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not able to use visibility due to how it the space is kept and with each window of the gallery being kept it would leave a lot of white space.

Comment: @j08691 Awesome thank you!, I'll go that route and hide it with document ready rather than default with `css` :)

Comment: OK, I'll post that as an answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the Google+ widget detects the space it's in, and in your case is shrinking from 96px to 80px. If you use JavaScript to render then hide it, instead of CSS, you get fix that with:

```
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    $('#parent-div').show();
});
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#parent-div').hide();
}, 0)
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/oxe968ux/1/)**